# Function which triggers when there is an event on a specific table in database with PARSE

Tags: ios, database, swift, parse-platform

I am developing an iOS analytic application (with Swift) that needs charts. The point is, I would like to update these charts when there is an update or insert in a specific table in database with Parse. I'm not looking for push notification and the Parse documentation doesn't mention a function to do that.

Is there a way to create a function which triggered when an event happens in a table for a specific user with Parse?

Thank you for your advice

Comment: You can use an aftersave cloud code function to trigger a push notification from the parse backend

Comment: How are you imagining it might work without push notifications?

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you for your quick answer Im checking this out

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this with cloud code..

Read [this guide](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide) how to get started.

Then you can use triggers like [beforeSave](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-onsave) or [afterSave](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-aftersave) or [beforeDelete](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-ondelete) and [afterDelete](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-afterdelete).

An example would be:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Review", function(request, response) {
  if (request.object.get("stars") < 1) {
    response.error("you cannot give less than one star");
  } else if (request.object.get("stars") > 5) {
    response.error("you cannot give more than five stars");
  } else {
    response.success();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I tested this and I have two different issues. In my swift code, the function afterSave is correctly called when I use MyPFOject.save() but I get an error when I use MyPFObject.saveInBackground() method. Do you know why?